# fullpage.js video end image show for every section

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, fullpage.js

I am trying to hide the video at the end and show up the image but its reloading every time. I tried all the possible way and i am very new with js.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            verticalCentered: true,
            onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
              //var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
              var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
              //var vidup = document.getElementById("yourVideo");
              //var hide = document.getElementsById('yourVideo')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
              if(direction ==='down'){
                    $('video').each(function () {
                        //playing the video
                        $(this).get(0).play();
                    });
                }
                else if(direction ==='up'){
                    $('video').each(function () {
                        //playing the video
                        $(this).get(0).play();
                    });
                }

            },//onLeave END
                afterRender: function () {
                    $('video').each(function () {
                        //playing the video
                        $(this).get(0).play();
                    });
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need help to load image after the video and evertime i comeback to the slide the video should autoplay and show the image at the end.

Comment: What is your problem? Where is the image in your javascript code? Why is `var img` commented? Which line are you using to show the image and hide the video?